# Android, creating an XML file that someone can modify after the app is installed

Tags: android

I am making an application that makes use of Google Cloud Messaging. I would like to make it so I can retrieve a string "SERVER_URL" from an XML file, and be able to modify this string without reinstalling the application.

*Such that;*

> The user takes their memory card out of the phone, puts it in their computer, they can now navigate through that memory card to find the XML file and modify the string SERVER_URL.

..After doing some research I am not certain I can access any XML data on an installed Android app without doing some kind of decompiling(I can't find anything readable on the memory card either). My original intent was to put this value simply inside 'strings.xml' of the android application. Any help on how to do so would be much appreciated, even if it is just for sure known that what I am trying to do is actually for sure not possible.

**Why do I want it this way ?**

This SERVER_URL value has potential to change(pilot project, things keep being moved), resulting in the app needing to be modified and reinstalled on all phones. We would like to avoid having to do this and instead just modify that file.

We do not, however, want to add functionality to the application to allow you to change SERVER_URL within the application itself, so that the user cannot so easily accidentally change this value if they are playing around with the phone(Mentally challenged users, caretakers would do the file modifying).

Thanks,

Wes

note: this is my first post on this site!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my first answer on this site!

Well, what you trying to do is to have configuration values out of the box. Since the application is about using internet resources, why don't you create a web service/site in which the caretakers can make the changes when necessary and your application can consume that value(s) on connection time.

So, the address of the server could change by version and all things done are transparent for the users.

Hope this help

Comment: Ya that is how I would like to do it, but the guy in charge of me is insisting I do it the other way :(.

Comment: Can't accept both answers but i'm going about it a different way, but this is for sure the more proper way you and Abhinav suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the settings in an xml file within your assets folder.
2. When the application starts, check whether the settings file is present on the required folder on your SDCard. If it's not, copy it from assets.
3. Read the setting from your SDCard folder, so that any changes are automatically reflected in the app.

However, I would advise you to put the setting within your app itself and use either of the two mechanisms -

1. Publish an update of the application when the setting changes and ask the user to update.
2. Store the setting in a DB or internal file, and regularly update it from the server using a background service or C2DM.

Comment: It does not appear in the SD card, but if I copy and paste the file over I still won't read from it unless I specify the direct path in the android folders right ?